# Checking if datetime is inside RRULE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There is a Google Calendar integration in the app I am working on. An **RRULE** string comes for recurring events describing their recurrence behaviour.

(e.g. RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20211215T215959Z;INTERVAL=3)


I need to verify some `DateTime`s in the app, so they do not intersect with those events. What is the most efficient way to do this, in terms of complexity?

Comment: You could try `iCal.NET`: [Working with recurring elements · rianjs/ical.net Wiki](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki/Working-with-recurring-elements)

Comment: @RichardDeeming, the library is actually almost what I needed, but some of the methods it has seem not to work properly. OccursOn and OccursAt to name a few are broken...

Answer (score 1):

If the format of that RRULE is constant, just:

1. Create a `Dictionary<string, string>`
2. Split it with the ";" character to get the different parts
3. Loop to these parts
4. In the loop split the part with the "=" character to get the rrule name and the rrule value.

The actual code should be pretty straightfordard.

```cs
// NOTE: This rules parsing code could/should make it into a separate function, this is just some quick coding

string[] rulesParts = myVariable.Substring(myVariable.Indexof(':') + 1).Split(';');
Dictionary<string, string> rrules = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(string rulePart in rulesParts)
{
    string[] nameAndValue = rulePart.Split(';');
    string ruleName = nameAndValue[0];
    string ruleValue = nameAndValue[1];
    if (!rulesParts.ContainsKey(ruleName))
    {
        rrules.Add(ruleName, ruleValue);
    }
}

if (rrules.ContainsKey("UNTIL"))
{
    // Do a DateTime.TryParseExact of rrules["UNTIL"] and work with your DateTime variable as you like
}
```

Comment: RRULE's UNTIL represents the date and time until the event is going to repeat, not the event's instance end time.